# Strange behaviour while concatenating two strings in ASP.NET (VB)

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

I am doing a simple concatenation using below line:

```
Response.Write("amount=" & 348 & "&currency=INR")
```

And it gives following output (a special character in between):

```
amount=348¤cy=INR
```

I also tried:

```
Response.Write("amount=" & Convert.ToString(348) & "&currency=INR")
```

That too gives the same output. It's something stupid but sorry I am stuck.

Comment: That symbol is the html entity for &curren; However, I am not using the semi colon. Is there a way out?

Comment: Tried the + also, same result. Thanks anyway.

Comment: change parameter name from currency to something else (i.e. cur=INR).

Comment: Yes, changing parameter works. But need to submit onward on a server which has specifications beyond my control.

Comment: Are you printing it in the href property of the <a> tab? If not, write &nbsp; instead of just &. Just look at the viewsource, you'll see right away if it's a vb.net problem or a browser problem.

Comment: No, I am displaying it plain text, not in any <> tag.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

```
 Protected Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
    Response.Write(String.Format("amount={0} & currency={1}INR", "10", "100"))
End Sub
```

Hope it helps